# Classification of $ \mathbb{Z}/p$-actions on $ \mathbb{Z}/p^n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

I have to prove the following lemma: let $p$ prime number, $n \in \mathbb{N}_{>1}$ and $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $a^p \equiv 1$ modulo $p^n$, thus we have the following cases

1) if $p$ is odd then $a \equiv 1$ mod $p^{n-1}$;

2)if $p=2$ then $a \equiv \pm1$ mod $2^{n-1}$.

I'm given the hint to use Fermat little theorem to prove the equality $a=1+kp^d$ where $p$ doesn't divide $k$ and $d>0$: to prove this formula is very easy but I don't understand how to use it to get the final result in the firts case.

I dealt 2) in the following way: knowing $a=1+k2^d$ we have $ a^2=1+k2^{d+1}+k^2 2^{2d} $ and imposing the condition $a^2 \equiv 1$ mod $2^n$ I can get the result  after various computations (here I omit them since they are trivial).

The problem is that I'm not sure this method works even for $p$ odd: I get by the usual formula
$a^p=(1+kp^d)^p= 1+\binom{p}{1}kp^d+\dots + (kp^d)^p$ so I have to impose 
 $\binom{p}{1}kp^d+ \binom{p}{2}k^2p^{2d}+\dots + (kp^d)^p\equiv 0$ mod $p^n$ but I don't get how this condition implies $d\geq n-1$.

Surely the point is that either my approach is not effective and I have to find another method or I'm passing over some basic number theory fact that would lead me to the conclusion.

Any help or advice is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1)\ $ is in fact a problem from [UNESCO Competition 1995](http://poncelet.math.nthu.edu.tw/usr2/imo_98/files/past-exams/romania/unesco95.html).

This follows from [Lifting the Exponent Lemma](http://www.taharut.org/imo/LTE.pdf) (LTE).

> If $p$ is odd, $a\equiv b\not\equiv 0\pmod{p}$, then $\upsilon_p\left(a^n-b^n\right)=\upsilon_p(a-b)+\upsilon_p(n)$.

$a^p\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ and $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ by [Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem).

Therefore $a^{\gcd(p,p-1)}\equiv a\equiv 1\not\equiv 0\pmod{p}$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/prove-that-gcdan-1-am-1-a-gcdn-m-1)), so by LTE:

$\upsilon_p(a^p-1^p)=\upsilon_p(a-1)+1=n\implies \upsilon_p(a-1)=n-1$.

So in fact we've proved a stronger statement: $p^{n-1}\mid a-1,\, p^n\nmid a-1$.

$2)\ $ We'll prove ($n\ge 2$): $\,2^n\mid (a+1)(a-1)\implies 2^{n-1}\mid a+1$ or $a-1$.

$a+1,a-1$ are even, $\gcd(a+1,a-1)=\gcd(2,a-1)=2$, so

$\upsilon_2(a\pm 1)=1,\,\upsilon_2(a\mp 1)\ge n-1$, and we're done.

Comment: I don't understand two points of the reasoning in the first part: 1) you say $a^{gcd(p,p-1)}\equiv a \equiv 1$ $(mod \ p)$ but being $p$ odd prime we have $gcd(p,p-1)=1$ so $a^{gcd(p,p-1)}=a$; 2) when applying the LTE to $a$ and $1$ you set $v_p(n)=1$: why is this? n is an arbitrary natural number greater than $1$.

Comment: @N.B. $\gcd(n,n-1)=1$ is true for any integer $n$. And you explained it yourself - $a^{\gcd(p,p-1)}=a$, so $a^{\gcd(p,p-1)}\equiv a\pmod{p}$, and by the lemma $\equiv 1\pmod{p}$. 2) Notice it's $a^p-1^p$, not $a^n-1^n$. I set $\upsilon_p(p)=1$.

Comment: @N.B. If it's still not clear, tell me, more specifically.

Comment: Ops, sorry for my heedless mystake. Nice proof of the first case, I didn't know the LTE so I couldn't provide it myself. Anyway the link you provided to the lemma doesn't work anymore: is it just a my problem or is it actually broken?

Comment: @N.B. It's broken indeed (wasn't when I posted it), but you can find it elsewhere, e.g. download the pdf from the author [here](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h393335).

Answer (score 2):

I think you were almost there. We want to prove that if $p$ is odd then $$a^p\equiv 1\pmod{p^n}\Rightarrow a\equiv 1\pmod{p^{n-1}}.$$

Let's prove by induction that for all $1\leq k\leq n-1$ we have $a\equiv 1\pmod{p^k}$. $k=1$ is obvious by Fermat's little theorem. 
Now write $a=1+p^kb$ for some $1\leq k\leq n-2$ and the condition becomes
$$a^p=(1+bp^k)^p=\sum_{j=0}^p {p\choose j}b^jp^{kj}\equiv 1\pmod{p^n}.$$
The first term in the sum is a $1$, the second is $bp^{k+1}$ and all the others are divisible by $p^{k+2}$ (because they contain a factor at least $p^{2k+1}$ thanks to the binomial coefficient and $2k+1\geq k+2$). Hence $1+bp^{k+1}\equiv 1\pmod{p^{k+2}}$ and so $p\mid b$. The thesis follows by induction on $k$.

Answer (score 1):

HIT:

For $n\ge3,$ $$a^2\equiv1\pmod{2^n}\implies2^{n-2}\mid\dfrac{a-1}2\cdot\dfrac{a+1}2$$

But $\dfrac{a+1}2-\dfrac{a-1}2=1$  so $\dfrac{a+1}2,\dfrac{a-1}2$ have opposite parities

If $\dfrac{a+1}2$ is odd, $2^{n-2}\mid\dfrac{a-1}2\iff a\equiv1\pmod{2^{n-1}}$

For $p>2$  use discrete logarithm

$$a^p\equiv1\pmod{p^n}\implies p\cdot\text{ind}(a)\equiv0\pmod{\phi(p^n)}$$